# Unable to deserialize the Subjects in this Context, cause: SecurityName is null

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, websphere, jaas, ltpa

I recently implemented LTPA (LDAP) authentication for a WebSphere application.  I've since seen the following error when attempting to make a web service call to an endpoint on a different domain:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Fault>
    <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
    <faultstring>java.io.IOException: Unable to deserialize the Subjects in this Context, cause: SecurityName is null</faultstring>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

The error is intermittent and to date I haven't been able to reliably reproduce it.
There are similar issues documented online but those appear to provide a little more information on the error given - I've been unable to find anything on this particular error.

Can anyone suggest what the issue might be here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is actually straightforward. The error message `Unable to deserialize the Subjects in this Context, cause: SecurityName is null` means that WebSphere is trying to deserialize a previously saved security context. The process fails because authentication using the LTPA token requires parameters such as `SecurityName`. This error message should also be logged in the SystemOut.log file, typically with an interval of 1 or 2 minutes.

Resolving the error correctly requires more information about your server environment. Assuming that it is a WAS-ND setup, you can shut down your nodes and use the `syncNode.sh` command to synchronize the configuration manually. This should resolve the issue.